# How to create a client table automatically after submitting form

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli, triggers

I need some theoretical assistance on the following project.

Lets suppose that i have a client form with the following input fields:

name, lastname, adress, body_weight & one submit button.

is there any way, after submitting form to auto create a mysql table where the data of the client will be stored. In addition, the same should happen for every new client, but for the exixting clients the data should be stored in the initial table.

Any thoughts on how this can be done or links to online examples would be really usefull.

Comment: Yes, use MySQL & PHP to create the table from the ajax data, after checking first if the table doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this SQL query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM :table_name)
  BEGIN
     UPDATE :table_name SET name=:name, lastname=:lastname, address:address, bodyweight:bodyweight;
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
     CREATE :table_name (
     name varchar(128),
     lastname varchar(128),
     address varchar(128),
     body_weight unsigned tinyint
     );
     INSERT INTO :table_name (name, lastname, address, bodyweight)
     VALUES (:name, :lastname, :address, :bodyweight);
  END
```